# linux + re-order lines in file according to machine NUMBER

Tags: awk, sed, perl

we have the following file

```
    more /home/list.in

    master01.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    master02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    master03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    worker01.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    worker02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    worker03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    worker05.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    worker06.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    worker07.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    worker08.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    worker09.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED

    master01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    master02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    master03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    worker01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    worker02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    worker03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    worker05.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    worker06.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    worker07.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    worker08.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    worker09.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

    master01.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    master02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    master03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    worker01.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    worker02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    worker03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    worker05.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    worker06.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    worker07.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    worker08.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    worker09.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
```

we want to re-order the file - list.in to the following structure (expected results)

so all the relevant lines to the machines number will be in the same group

expected results

```
    master01.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    master01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    master01.fsdns.com HDFS  STARTED

    master02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    master02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    master02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED

    master03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    master03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    master03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
    .
    .
    .
    .
    . 
    worker09.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
    worker09.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
    worker09.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
```

what I have tried until now

```
 for i in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
 do
  grep  worker$i /tmp/list.in
 done


 worker01.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
 worker01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
 worker01.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
 worker02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
 worker02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
 worker02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
 worker03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
 worker03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
 worker03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
 worker05.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
 worker05.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
 worker05.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
 worker06.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
 worker06.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
 worker06.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
 worker07.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
 worker07.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
 worker07.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
```

Comment: Please stop tagging your text processing questions as `linux` and `bash`.

Comment: And what have *you* tried?

Comment: not succeeded with awk ,

Comment: Paste what you have tried. We aren't here to do your job for you.

Comment: I try also with simple loop but not completed successfully ( first need space between each machine category to the next category , second bad idea to set hard coded numbers  as 01 02 03 etc

Comment: What's *really* ironic is that **this is trivially easy if you store your info in an SQL-based database.**  But instead, you're trying to parse the log info for your NoSQL Hadoop/Ambari cluster with ad hoc text processing tools.  What's wrong with this picture?

Comment: the output comes from curl command line ( API ) , so this output is after I filter many lines and words

Comment: With a slightly different output: `sort -t '.' -k1.1,1.0 file`

Comment: nice but what about the space between machines diff number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sort -k1,1 list.in  | 
    awk '
      /^[[:space:]]*$/ { next };
      lasthost == "" { lasthost = $1 };
      $1 == lasthost { print $0; next };
      {print "\n" $0 ; lasthost=$1 }' 
master01.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
master01.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
master01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

master02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
master02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
master02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

master03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
master03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
master03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

worker01.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker01.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

worker02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

worker03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

worker05.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker05.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker05.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

worker06.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker06.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker06.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

worker07.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker07.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker07.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

worker08.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker08.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker08.fsdns.com YARN STARTED

worker09.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker09.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker09.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
```

The awk script keeps track of the last hostname seen in field $1, and prints a newline before the current input line whenever it changes.  It also skips any lines that are either completely empty or contain only whitespace characters.

To avoid printing a blank line before the first record, it also checks if the `lasthost` variable is empty (i.e. undefined), and sets it if it is.

Answer (score 1):

If the blank lines aren't important to you, a simple sorting command could be:

```
sort -t. -k1 /home/list.in
```

which results in (with leading blank lines):

```
master01.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
master01.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
master01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
master02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
master02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
master02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
master03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
master03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
master03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker01.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker01.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker05.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker05.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker05.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker06.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker06.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker06.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker07.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker07.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker07.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker08.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker08.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker08.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker09.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker09.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker09.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
awk '$1{a[$1];b[$2]}
END{asorti(a);for( i in a){for(j in b){printf("%s %s\n",a[i],j)};printf("\n")}}' file
```

`$1` For a first field not empty
`{a[$1];b[$2]}` create arrays a and b
`END{` After all the file has been read in
`asorti(a)` sort the array a
`for( i in a ){` for each machine
`for(j in b){` for each server
`printf("%s %s\n",a[i],j)};` print the values sorted
`printf("\n")}` print one new (empty) line
`}' file` for the input file.

Answer (score -1):

Used Awk and sed to achieve the same. As tested it works fine

```
i=`awk -F "." '{print $1}' l.txt  | sed '/^$/d' | sed  "s/\s+//g" | sort -u`; for j in $i; do sed -n "/$j/p" l.txt; done
```

output

```
master01.fsdns.comAMBARI_METRICS STARTED
master01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
master01.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
master02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
master02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
master02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
master03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
master03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
master03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker01.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker01.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker01.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker02.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker02.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker02.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker03.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker03.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker03.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker05.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker05.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker05.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker06.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker06.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker06.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker07.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker07.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker07.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker08.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker08.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker08.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
worker09.fsdns.com AMBARI_METRICS STARTED
worker09.fsdns.com YARN STARTED
worker09.fsdns.com HDFS STARTED
```

Comment: Please explain why you down voted for me