# How to append the begining of a file with text from STDIN

Tags: bash, sed, files, text

I'm working to debug some kind of issue with the [Nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/master/scripts/install-multi-user.sh) Linux installer script on Debian-based OSs

Like what was said [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/4663#issuecomment-805192895), this snippet of the `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```bsh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

will render some Nix commands inoperative as some run in non-interactive shells, so it needs to be sourced before that snippet

I came up with that command as an example which would run just fine at a single exception

`sudo sed -i '1i source /etc/profile.d/nix.sh' /etc/bash.bashrc`

In the Nix script, the init function is already provided by the `shell_source_lines()` function, and piped to the `configure_shell_profile()` function's `tee -a` command, so it is appending the file, I need it to append the beginning, while keeping the piping

```bsh
shell_source_lines() {
    cat <<EOF

# Nix
if [ -e '$PROFILE_NIX_FILE' ]; then
  . '$PROFILE_NIX_FILE'
fi
# End Nix

EOF
}

configure_shell_profile() {
    for profile_target in "${PROFILE_TARGETS[@]}"; do
        if [ -e "$profile_target" ]; then
            _sudo "to back up your current $profile_target to $profile_target$PROFILE_BACKUP_SUFFIX" \
                  cp "$profile_target" "$profile_target$PROFILE_BACKUP_SUFFIX"
        else
            # try to create the file if its directory exists
            target_dir="$(dirname "$profile_target")"
            if [ -d "$target_dir" ]; then
                _sudo "to create a stub $profile_target which will be updated" \
                    touch "$profile_target"
            fi
        fi
# What I need to modify :
        if [ -e "$profile_target" ]; then
            shell_source_lines \
                | _sudo "extend your $profile_target with nix-daemon settings" \
                        tee -a "$profile_target" # Needs to be replaced
        fi
    done
}
```

I can't find a way to prepend a file with text from STDIN, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587615/unix-command-to-prepend-text-to-a-file or this https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash answer your question?

Comment: @QuoraFeans Not quite, the command would run just fine, but I have to deal with the pipe, and I have no idea how to make sed work w/that

Comment: Could you just create new temporary file that has *new_content* + *old_content* then replace file?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this command with a GNU sed version.

```
tee -a "$profile_target"
```

```
sed -i -e '1r /dev/stdin' -e '1N' "$profile_target"
```

- Assuming the input is atleast 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /dev/stdin file.txt
```

takes the input from stdin and writes it to stdout, followed by the contents of `file.txt`.

So for example, if `file.txt` contains (line numbers for illustration only, not part of the file contents)

```
1  This is some text in the
2  text file. 
3  It has three lines.
```

then

```
echo "Prepended text line" | cat /dev/stdin file.txt > combined.txt
```

results in file `combined.txt` containing

```
1  Prepended text line
2  This is some text in the
3  text file. 
4  It has three lines.
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepending lines at the beginning of a file isn't as easy as it sound, and usually use a temp file (like what `sed -i` do) behind the scene.

```bsh
cat > data.new && mv data.new "$profile_target"
```

or for a faster solution, but that require external tool (`sponge` from `moreutils`):

```bsh
cat - "$profile_target" | sponge "$profile_target"
```

Note:

- This doesn't check if the input is empty (coming from stdin) because if it is, it will add whitespace/blank at the start of the file.
- This also doesn't make handle error of any kind. So make sure you have backup of whatever file you use this on or use a safer approach.

references: [How to add lines/text to the beginning of a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417724/how-to-add-lines-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file)